How to set CPU turbo frequency limit using acpi-cpufreq driver in Linux
I'm using a clevo laptop with a desktop i5-11400 CPU. I have disabled the intel_pstate driver in kernel command line to use cpufreq driver for frequency scaling. But when I tried to set frequency limit with sudo cpupower frequency-set -u, I found that I was only able to set frequency values in non-turbo range, and tying to use frequency in the turbo range will set the limit to the max turbo frequency. While I was using intel_pstate driver, I could set frequency percentage in /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct so I was able to limit the frequency to any values. How can I do this with the cpufreq driver?
OS: debian12
